# 403 Forbidden on saving admin configuration in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, nginx, http-status-403

Getting 403 Forbidden error while saving the Admin Catalog -> Catalog configuration only. Remaining all configurations are saving without any error.

And also, When Save/Update the products which are having product images are also leads to 403 error. The Products which doesn't have Images are updating well.

I have verified Folder and File Permissions and those are have 755, 644 respectivly.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Any solution, please?

Comment: @mahmoudismail, we have faced this issue due to the rules configured on the firewall side. Our it team has updated the rules and fixed the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply.